# Can I merge a node server with the polymer init starter-kit application?

Tags: node.js, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I have my fledgling polymer application running.  I would like to load and save a file.  I would like to do that by using the ajax element.  But what happens on the server side?

I have made nodejs express applications before.  I could make a separate server for the client to talk to.  But there are at least two other options:

1. Take the front-end material supplied by the polymer start-kit and put it in the /public directory of an express application.
2. Put express routes in my polymer starter-kit application.

I am inclined to bring Express into the existing start-kit application.  But maybe someone else has already tried this, and can tell me what I will run into?

I looked at the starter-kit code a little bit.  Apparently, it uses the spdy package and not the http package, but I can work with that.  That's as far as I have gotten.  Any advice?

Regards, Rick

Comment: Just to add a little clarity.  This is one program, that functions with a server portion and a client portion.  Kind of like Electron, but with an actually separate client process and server process, possibly on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the guys on the Polymer slack channel.  Thanks, milesje.  `polymer serve` is just supposed to be a light server to serve static files.  If you want to do something more substantial, you should create your own server (nodejs or something else) and put your Polymer files in the public/ directory.

Hope this saves someone else some time.

Comment: Hey super awesome thank you! do you know of a guide to do this? I've inherited an polyer app and trying to merg that work into the node.js app I already have

Comment: No, I don't know of a guide.  Maybe go back to the well -- polymer slack channel -- and ask.  It's not strictly a polymer question, but they like polymer apps to go forward and succeed.